# How to make an url with GET /repos/:owner/:repo/labels/:name

Tags: ios, swift, github, alamofire

I referenced GitHub how-to-use stuff and I found this ; GET /repos/:owner/:repo/labels/:name. But I have no idea how to use it. How do I read it and how do I implement it as url?  I know this is basic but I am new to use JSON so its helpful if you help me

Answer (score 1):

This is a GitHub API definition for [getting a single issue label](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/#get-a-single-label)

To use a GitHub API, see the [Getting Started section](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/labels/#get-a-single-label)

You are supposed to:

- replace `:owner` with the owner GitHub account of the repo
- replace `:repo` with the name of the GitHub repo which has the issue labels you want
- replace `:name` with the issue label name you want to get

Example:

https://api.github.com/repos/docker/docker/labels/roadmap

This is the [label `roadmap` of the repo docker/docker](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues?q=is%3Aopen%20is%3Aissue%20label%3Aroadmap).